# Sorting array of dates and returning the index in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, date, indexing

I have an array of dates

```
@dates = qw(2/1/1989 2/1/1970 2/1/1970 2/1/1989 6/1/1970 12/1/1970);
```

I need to sort this from oldest to newest and return the index of unsorted array after sorting.

Output should something like this

```
#sorted array
2/1/1970
2/1/1970
6/1/1970
12/1/1970
2/1/1989
2/1/1989

#indexes
1 2 4 5 0 3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are these international dates, or North American?

Answer (score 1):

```
my @dates = qw(2/1/1989 2/1/1970 2/1/1970 2/1/1989 6/1/1970 12/1/1970);

my @idx = map $_->[0],
  sort {
    # compare years
    $a->[3] <=> $b->[3] ||
    # compare months
    $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] ||
    # compare days
    $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] ||
    # compare index for stable sort for duplicate values
    $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] 
  }
  map [$_, split /\D/, $dates[$_] ],
  0 .. $#dates;

print "indexes @idx\n";
# sorted values
print "$_\n" for @dates[@idx];
```

output

```
indexes 1 2 4 5 0 3
2/1/1970
2/1/1970
6/1/1970    
12/1/1970
2/1/1989
2/1/1989
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) and a [`Schwartzian Transform`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my @dates = qw(2/1/1989 2/1/1970 2/1/1970 2/1/1989 6/1/1970 12/1/1970);

my @idx = map { $_->[0] }
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
    map { [$_, Time::Piece->strptime($dates[$_], '%m/%d/%Y') ] }
    (0..$#dates);

print "Indexes: @idx\n";

print "Dates: @dates[@idx]\n";
```

Outputs:

```
Indexes: 1 2 4 5 0 3
Dates: 2/1/1970 2/1/1970 6/1/1970 12/1/1970 2/1/1989 2/1/1989
```

Could also just do the following:

```
my @idx = sort { 
    Time::Piece->strptime($dates[$a], '%m/%d/%Y') <=> Time::Piece->strptime($dates[$b], '%m/%d/%Y')
} (0..$#dates);
```